# Change the drag of ListItem.Swipeable from React Native Elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements, react-native-gesture-handler

I've been using the `Swipeable` component from react-native-gesture-handler to handle my swipeable list items, but Swipeable is causing lag on the JS thread during the initial render, according to my profilers. So I've decided to switch to `ListItem.Swipeable` from React Native Elements. The initial render lag is gone, which is great, but it requires too much drag to swipe from left to right and vice versa. I've looked through the documentation of Listem.Swipeable, but I don't see any way to manipulate the drag.

Is there a way to change the drag value?

Relevant ListItemSwipeable component:

```
<ListItem.Swipeable
      rightWidth={ScreenWidth / 2}
      rightContent={() => <Buttons />}
    >
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AccordionListItem item={item} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</ListItem.Swipeable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit older now, but just saw this `minSlideWidth` that is available on version 4.0.0-rc.8 of React Native elements.

https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/listItem_swipeable#props